# Putting matlab code into python

Tags: python, matlab

I got a little problem in putting the code from matlab into python, i know how to make loops and stuff but the double equal sign is the same as function is member and I have no idea how to put it in python

```
for i=1:49
    if path==var(path(1),i) == 0 & var(path(1),i) ~= 0
        path(1,2) = var(r,i);
        var2(i,1:2)  = path;
        path(1,1:2);
        a = a+1;
        two_connections(a,:) = path;
```

Comment: What is `path`? What does `var(..., i)` do? (The docs don't allow that construction: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/var.html.) What is this code means to do?

Comment: `==` has the same meaning in Matlab as in Python. Your question is unclear

Comment: @katrielalex: I'm guessing `var` in this case is an array that he defined elsewhere, rather than the function.

Answer (score 1):

The double double equal sign in Matlab tests whether each value is equivalent.

In other words (a==b==c) will evaluate to 1 if a,b,c are equivalent, and 0 otherwise (even if a==b.)

It is sufficient to ensure that a==b and b==c (or a==b and a==c, etc.)

The tilde equals sign is simply "not equal to".

So your if statement would look like:

```
if (path == 0) and (var(path(1),i) == 0) and (var(path(1),i) != 0):
```

Comment: Note that `is` and `==` is not equivalent. If you create a class `Z` with this method: `def __eq__(self, other): return 0 == other`, then `Z() == 0` is `True`, while `Z() is 0` is `False`. I think `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: That is a very good point and I didn't mean to be misleading.  In this case, however, both statements will evaluate the same way.

Comment: -can you edit your answer so that "is" is not shown as equivalent to "==" ? Otherwise it deserves to be downvoted

Comment: @jsbueno -- I had thought about that, but didn't want to destroy the context of the comments -- but per your suggestion, I deleted it -- thanks!